# How to get_terms $count for custom-taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, get, taxonomy-terms

Have a `custom-taxonomy` called `campaign_action` with three categories called `draft`, `live` and `paused`.

I would like to display just the count for each but not in a list.

For example, I would like to echo the count for each individually as -

```
<li>Draft (<?php //code to display a number count for drafts ?>)</li>
<li>Live (<?php //code to display a number count for live ?>)</li>
<li>Paused (<?php //code to display a number count for paused ?>)</li>
```

I have successfully done this by displaying

```
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
   echo '(' . $term->count . ')';
 }
```

However, this does not work for me and I want to get the `$count` for each individually.

Thank you for your help.

**EDIT**

To show further what I have in place currently

```
    <?php  
$terms = get_terms('campaign_action');

 if ( !empty( $terms ) && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ){

 echo '(0)';
 foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
   echo '(' . $term->count . ')';
 }
 } 
?>
```

This will show all counts for each individual category but I only want to show the count for the category of `draft` within the `custom_taxonomy` of `campaign_action`

Here is an image of what the above achieves when added to the end of the Drafts. I want it to only show the count for the category of `drafts` within the `custom-taxonomy` of `campaign_action`. If it has zero posts with that category then it should show zero.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try below code and read my comments of code.

```
echo wp_list_categories( array(
    'orderby'    => 'name',
    'show_count' => true,
    'taxonomy'   => 'campaign_action' //i guess campaign_action  is your  taxonomy 
) );
```

There is second way as well for custom html layout please check below code for custom html layout

```
$terms = get_terms(array(
 'taxonomy' => 'campaign_action',//i guess campaign_action  is your  taxonomy 
 'hide_empty' => false
));
echo $terms->name;
echo $terms->count;
```

**After Your question is edited :**

```
$terms = get_terms(array(
'taxonomy' => 'campaign_action',//i guess campaign_action  is your  taxonomy 
'hide_empty' => false
));
foreach ($terms as $terms)
{
    if($terms->name == 'Draft') 
    {
        echo $terms->name;
        echo $terms->count; 
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, unfortunately, this will not show the `count` for each individual `category`. If I were to want to `echo` only the `draft` `count` how would I achieve this?

Comment: can you check the taxonomy slug because this code is working for my product_cat slug. you can put the condition for display post coutn for specific category

Comment: I have updated the question to help with my goal. The code you have supplied works but not to achieve what I need. Adding the `condition for display post coutn for specific category` is where I am struggling.

Comment: Is there a way to add the condition to remove `posts` that have been deleted? And only show the published 'post' count.

Comment: If you wish to do like that than according to me you need to go with paul's answer but delete post will never be counted

Answer (score -1):

You need to some arguments :

```
<?php
$args = array(
     'post_type' => 'campaign_action',
     'post_status' => 'publish' //(Or Draft...etc)
);
$show_recipes= get_posts( $args );
echo $show_recipes->post_count;
?>
```

Here is the full list of statuses in WP : https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status

Comment: Thank you for your help, the `categories` of `draft`, `paused`, and `live are within the `custom-post-type` and not `post_status`

Comment: I think I don't undertstand you point. Perhaps check this link : https://github.com/jenwachter/wp-custom-post-status

Comment: Thank you, Paul. I have updated the question to help with my goal. We are not using the Post Status or adding to a custom-post-status.